# Firestore / Flutter - How can I get document Id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code

```
Future _save() async {

final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('product/'+nameController.text+'.jpg');
final StorageUploadTask task = storageRef.putFile(_image);
StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await task.onComplete;
String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
StorageMetadata created = await taskSnapshot.ref.getMetadata();

Firestore.instance.collection('product').document()
    .setData({
  'name': nameController.text,
  'price': int.tryParse(priceController.text),
  'description': descriptionController.text,
  'creator': widget.user.uid,
  'created': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.creationTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
  'modified': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.updatedTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
  'url': downloadUrl,
  'id': //I want to set document Id here //
});
}
```

how can I get this random generated document's ID?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After `collection` you can add a `document` and receive the `DocumentReference` .

```
  final docRef = await Firestore.instance.collection('product').add({
    'name': nameController.text,
    'price': int.tryParse(priceController.text),
    'description': descriptionController.text,
    'creator': widget.user.uid,
    'created': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.creationTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
    'modified': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.updatedTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
    'url': downloadUrl,
  });
```

Now you can get the document ID:

```
 docRef.documentID
```

Answer (score 7):

you do it like that

```
DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('product').document();    
documentReference.setData({
        'name': nameController.text,
        'price': int.tryParse(priceController.text),
        'description': descriptionController.text,
        'creator': widget.user.uid,
        'created': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.creationTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
        'modified': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(created.updatedTimeMillis, isUtc: true).toString(),
        'url': downloadUrl,
        'id': documentReference.documentID
      });
```

Document ID

```
documentReference.documentID
```

Answer (score 5):

Since v0.14.0 of the [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog) package:

> DEPRECATED: documentID has been deprecated in favor of id.

so instead of

```
ref.documentId
```

use

```
ref.id
```

to retriev the random generated document id.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID by calling your ref.documentID

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the partgiculer ***documentId*** using **value.Id**.

```
 CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('candidates');
      
      Future<void> registerUser() {
     // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
         return users.add({
          'name': enteredTextName, // John Doe
          'email': enteredTextEmail, // Stokes and Sons
          'profile': dropdownValue ,//
          'date': selectedDate.toLocal().toString() ,//// 42
        })
            .then((value) =>(showDialogNew(value.id)))
            .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
      }
```