# Get Document ID of Firestore Document (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGE95.png)
Trying already for a couple of days to get document id of a document in Firestore from my Flutter app.
what I want is to update or delete document, but have to identify it first by his id.
I have that ID with other values like name, address, etc.., when I open Firestore.

Now I am trying to understand how to get document id into a variable, which I then use in my function to delete or update the document.

```
getDocIndex() {
  var documentID = Firestore.instance
      .collection('Requests')
      .document(widget.data['Document ID'].toString())
      .get();
  print(documentID);
}
```

I understand that widget in a function is not usable. Maybe something with snapshot.data.... but its also marked as red.

This is my function which then should work:

```
deleteDocument(){

Firestore.instance.collection('Requests').document(documentID).delete();

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Yuj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvgyL.png)

Comment: check out this link.. [link to your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605611/firestore-flutter-how-can-i-get-document-id)

Comment: Check this link... this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605611/firestore-flutter-how-can-i-get-document-id)

Comment: You actually know the ID while requesting the document. What's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is, that I need that ID when I am using an app. I don't want to open Firestore to get that id. When I open a Firestores document which is a request from a user, I want to delete it from my app. And to delete it, I can do it by using an ID of a document. So I need a variable which gets an ID from opened document

Comment: @MichaelKarp please share a screenshot of your Firestore structure as well as the Flutter code so we can test stuff. Also what is marked in red?

Comment: @MichaelKarp please hover on the red lines you are referring to and share a screenshot of that so we can see what the actual error is. Also please paste the code for your widget.

Comment: I think only what I need at the moment is just to get a value of my field "Document ID" in the Document of Firestore. After that I will have that ID in a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
getDocIndex() {
  var document = Firestore.instance
      .collection('Requests')
      .document(widget.data['Document ID'].toString())
      .get();
  print(document.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but widget and id are marked red.   Also I think its all difficult, because I have in one dart file the function where users adds his request and in other dart file where I am trying to get that document. So my variable docId is in other dart file. I wanted to get the id when I am using my key "Document ID" from document.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:kuechenrechner/card_widget.dart';
import 'package:kuechenrechner/gmaps.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'adminslogin.dart';

//final documentsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('Requests');

class Admins extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminsState createState() => _AdminsState();
}

class _AdminsState extends State<Admins> {
  /*geoConvert() async {
// Geocoding for Address
// final query = "1600 Amphiteatre Parkway, Mountain View";
    var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
    var first = addresses.first;
    print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
  }
*/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AdminsLogin();
              }));
            }),
        title: Text(
          'Anfragen',
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: AdminsList(),
    );
  }
}

Future getPosts() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore
      .collection("Requests")
      .orderBy('Anfrage vom')
      .getDocuments();

  return qn.documents;
}

//Abfrage DocumentID
getDocIndex() async {
  /* var documentID = Firestore.instance
      .collection('Requests')
      .document(widget.data['Document ID'].toString())
      .get();
  print(documentID);
  */

  var document = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Requests')
      .document(widget.data['Document ID'].toString())
      .get();
  print(document.id);
}

class AdminsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminsListState createState() => _AdminsListState();
}

class _AdminsListState extends State<AdminsList> {
  navigateToDetail(DocumentSnapshot post) {
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminsDetails(post: post)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getPosts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Loading...'),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.separated(
                reverse: true,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      '${snapshot.data[index].data['Name']}',
                      style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      '${snapshot.data[index].data['Anfrage vom']}',
                      style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                    ),
                    onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.business_center,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getDocIndex();
                        }),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}

class AdminsDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot post;
  AdminsDetails({this.post});

  @override
  _AdminsDetailsState createState() => _AdminsDetailsState();
}

String keyID;

class _AdminsDetailsState extends State<AdminsDetails> {
  //Anfragen löschen intern
  deleteDocument() async {
    /* CollectionReference collectionReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection("Requests");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.getDocuments();

    querySnapshot.documents[0].reference.delete();
*/

    Firestore.instance.collection('Requests').document(keyID).delete();
  }

  //Anfragen intern ändern, anpassen! Button in der Appbar!
  TextEditingController adminComment = TextEditingController();
  updateData() async {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection("Requests");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.getDocuments();
    querySnapshot.documents[0].reference
        .updateData({'Administrator Anmerkung': adminComment.text});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Anfrage von ${widget.post.data["Name"]}',
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  updateData();
                });
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Kontaktdaten des Kunden: ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => customLaunch(
                      'mailto:${widget.post.data["Email"]}?subject=Feed%20back&body=Write your%20feedback'),
                  child: Text('Email: ${widget.post.data["Email"]}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.amber),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      customLaunch('tel: ${widget.post.data["Telefon"]}'),
                  child: Text('Telefon: ${widget.post.data["Telefon"]}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                ),
                Divider(),
                Text(
                  'Kundenanschrift: ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('${widget.post.data["Anschrift"]}'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return MapsDemo();
                  })),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Divider(),
                Text(
                  'Kommentar:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text('${widget.post.data["Kommentar"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                Divider(),
                Text(
                  'Details der Anfrage: ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text('Anfrage vom: ${widget.post.data["Anfrage vom"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text('Küchenlänge: ${widget.post.data["Küchenlaenge"]} Meter',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text('Hängeschränke: ${widget.post.data["Hängeschränke"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Gebrauchte Küche: ${widget.post.data["Gebrauchte Küche"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Arbeitsplatte schneiden: ${widget.post.data["Arbeitsplatte bearbeiten"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Anschluss Waschmaschine: ${widget.post.data["Anschluss WaMa"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Anschluss Spülmaschine: ${widget.post.data["Anschluss Spuel"]}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Anschluss Herd: ${widget.post.data["Anschluss Herd"]}',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Wunschdatum Montage: ${widget.post.data["Wunschdatum"]}',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Gesamt geschätzt: ${widget.post.data["Gesamt geschätzt"]} Euro',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
                TextField(
                    controller: adminComment,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Anmerkung Administrator:',
                    )),
                //Kommentare von Administratoren:
                Container(
                    child: Text(
                  '${widget.post.data['Administrator Anmerkung']}',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                )),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Diese Anfrage wirklich löschen?',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca()),
                                actions: [
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: Text('Abbrechen')),
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        setState(() {
                                          deleteDocument();
                                          Navigator.push(context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                                  (BuildContext context) {
                                            return Admins();
                                          }));
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Text('Löschen')),
                                ],
                              );
                            }));
                          },
                          child: Text('Anfrage löschen')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values inside the document, you can use a where query to find all documents that have those parameters.

```js
Firestore.instance.collection('requests').where('Document ID', isEqualTo: "ID")
    .snapshots().listen(
          (data) => print('grower ${data.documents[0]['name']}')
    );
```

However, if you already have access to the document's data locally, you can pull the reference path from the document snapshot if you have stored it locally. It is only an issue of recovering that data from within your app at that point.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the ID, but only from first document in the list with a position [0]. So I need to find out how to make that 0 flexible. That the system identifies the position of a document in Firestore. It worked for me without .where('Document ID')

Comment: With this I get all Document IDs from a Map....but need only one which I choose     Future getDocIndex() async {
  Firestore.instance.collection('Requests').snapshots().listen((data) => print(
      'ID: ${data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document['Document ID'])}'));
}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I've got it!

```
return ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          '${snapshot.data[index].data['Name']}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          '${snapshot.data[index].data['Anfrage vom']}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]);
                          keyID = snapshot.data[index].data['Document ID'];
                          print(keyID.toString());
```

Below I get in keyID the Document ID from field in a document. After that I can use the delete function with ID reference.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Requests').document(keyID).delete();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
getDocIndex() async {
  var document = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Requests')
      .document(widget.data['Document ID'].toString())
      .get();
  print(document.id);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @michael-karp it could always be great if you could provide your firestore structure to help on the query structure. 
Remember you are getting a value from the Future always has to put async before the func body and away with int the function otherwise you might either have a null value or throw an expection.

Comment: @menotenhanga Thank you! the problem is, when I am trying to upload more than 3 pictures, I get an error here. So I can't post the full code. Below is your answer and I get two mistakes. the system doesn't know what is widget here and document.id -> doesn't recognize the word id. Its not defined.

Comment: @menotenhanga i have put an answer from that file here. So here is the full code of that file

Comment: At the moment I use that function which updates the document, and also equal which deletes document. But problem ist that it updates/deletes always the first document in a Map, because of [0] index. If I could manage to find out the current Index, maybe I could solve my problem that way.

Comment: TextEditingController adminComment = TextEditingController();
  updateData() async {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection("Requests");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.getDocuments();
    querySnapshot.documents[0].reference
        .updateData({'Administrator Anmerkung': adminComment.text});
  }